# How to get username string from a JSON object after matching the user id with a second JSON that only holds the user id

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to iterate through 2 different JSON objects.

The first holds ORDERS data containing `orderId` `userId` and `productId` like this:

```
[{  
    "orderId": 1, 
    "userId": 1,
    "productId": 001
  },
  {  
    "orderId": 2, 
    "userId": 2,
    "productId": 001
  },
  {  
    "orderId": 3, 
    "userId": 2,
    "productId": 002
  },
  {  
    "orderId": 4, 
    "userId": 2,
    "productId": 002
  },
  {  
    "orderId": 5, 
    "userId": 3,
    "productId": 003
  },
  {  
    "orderId": 6, 
    "userId": 1,
    "productId": 003
  },
  {  
    "orderId": 7, 
    "userId": 1,
    "productId": 003
  }

]
```

The second JSON holds the users data like this:

```
[{  
    "userId": 1,
    "name": "john", 
    "email": "john@gmail.com"
  },
  {  
    "userId": 2,
    "name": "mike", 
    "email": "mike@gmail.com"
  },
  {  
    "userId": 3,
    "name": "jane", 
    "email": "jane@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

There is a third JSON object that contains the product data. included below for context:

```
[
  {  
    "productId": 001,
    "productName": "square"
  },
  {  
    "productId": 002,
    "productName": "triangle"
  },
  {  
    "productId": 003,
    "productName": "hexagon"
  }
]
```

What I'm trying to do is to compare the USERS and ORDERS objects and output the **USER NAME** (not ID) of all orders that have purchased **HEXAGON**.

The code I'm using is the following:

```
const getUserNamesFromOrders = (productName) => {
    const products = require('./resources/products.json')
  for (product of products) {
    if (product.productName === productName) {
      const productId = product.productId   
      const orders = require('./resources/orders.json')
      const users = require('./resources/users.json')
      for (order of orders) {
        const userId = order.userId 
        if (order.productId === productId) {
            for (user of users) {
                if(user.userId === order.userId) {
                   const userName = user.name
                   allUsers.push(userName)
                }
            }
        }

      }
    } 
  }
    return allUsers
} 

getUserNamesFromOrders('hexagon');
```

The above code currently outputs and array showing

`['john','john']`

When it SHOULD BE DISPLAYING

`['john','jane']`

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should work as it is. But instead of nested `for` loops, you can use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) methods to make it more readable.

First you have to find the `productId` of given `productName`. Then filter orders by `productId`. And then for each order, find `name` from `users` array based on `userId`.

```
const getUserNamesFromOrders = (productName) => {
  const products = require('./resources/products.json')
  const orders = require('./resources/orders.json');
  const users = require('./resources/users.json');

  let usernames = new Set(); // Using Set to avoid storing duplicate usernames.

  let productId = products.find(product => product.productName === productName).productId;

  let filteredOrders = orders.filter(order => order.productId === productId);

  filteredOrders.forEach(order => {
    let user = users.find(user => user.userId === order.userId);
    usernames.add(user.name);
  });

  return Array.from(usernames);
} 

let usernames = getUserNamesFromOrders('hexagon');
console.log(usernames);
```

**Live Example:**

```js
let orders = [{ "orderId": 1, "userId": 1, "productId": 001 }, { "orderId": 2, "userId": 2, "productId": 001 }, { "orderId": 3, "userId": 2, "productId": 002 }, { "orderId": 4, "userId": 2, "productId": 002 }, { "orderId": 5, "userId": 3, "productId": 003 }, { "orderId": 6, "userId": 1, "productId": 003 }, { "orderId": 7, "userId": 1, "productId": 003 } ];
let users = [{ "userId": 1, "name": "john", "email": "john@gmail.com" }, { "userId": 2, "name": "mike", "email": "mike@gmail.com" }, { "userId": 3, "name": "jane", "email": "jane@gmail.com" } ];
let products = [ { "productId": 001, "productName": "square" }, { "productId": 002, "productName": "triangle" }, { "productId": 003, "productName": "hexagon" } ];

const getUserNamesFromOrders = (productName) => {

let usernames = new Set(); // Using Set to avoid storing duplicate usernames.

  let productId = products.find(product => product.productName === productName).productId;

  let filteredOrders = orders.filter(order => order.productId === productId);
 
  filteredOrders.forEach(order => {
    let user = users.find(user => user.userId === order.userId);
    usernames.add(user.name);
  });

  return Array.from(usernames);
} 

let usernames = getUserNamesFromOrders('hexagon');
console.log(usernames);
```

Comment: Hi @Nikhil, this is almost working. The only issue I see is that the code is returning a single username `john` which is the one that should be duplicated, but returns it only once, so the Set90; is doing its job, but it doesn't seem to iterate through `jane`'s order

Comment: @user3354949 - It should give the expected output. See the live example I added in my answer. Make sure your JSON files are correct.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info @Nikhil. Something funny is happening with this, I can clearly see in your newest example that, when you embed the 3 objects at the top within variables, the function works perfectly, but when I `require` the object from within the function, it doesn't seem to loop through all the available orders. Any ideas what could be the problem? The JSON files seem to be correct and they work independently in other functions that target products and users separately

Comment: @user3354949 - In your JSON files, make sure you have quotes `""` for strings such as `name` and no quotes for Ids such as `userId`, `productId`. Also you can use [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com) to validate your JSON files and find any errors.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following, instead of the for-of-loops:

```
allUsers = [...new Set(orders
  .filter(o => o.productId === productName)
  .map(o => users.find(u => u.userId === o.userId).name))];
```

First I filter out all orders not containing the required item, then I get all the related usernames and lastly I filter out duplicates by casting to a Set and spreading that.

Answer (score 0):

I replay your code in this [JS snipped](https://jsfiddle.net/hp2fnme9/), and always work.

I've changed two things:

1) Make `productId` values as string values

2) Change condition `if (product.productName === productName)` to `if (product.productId === productName)` because product name that you pass is actually productId.

Comment: Sorry Ilya, I have noticed an important detail and error in my original code for the products table which I have corrected now. The `productId` is an integer value and the `productName` is a string, which is the value passed to the function. Additionally, the resulting usernames should be delivered in an array without any duplicate values

Comment: @user3354949 - Do `orders` have `productId` or `productName`?

Comment: @Nikhil, sorry, orders have `productId`

Answer (score 0):

```
const getUserNamesFromOrders = (productName) => {
   // Returns ordered items associated with the product name
   const ordered = orders.filter(o => {
     const productId = products.filter(p => p.productName === productName)[0].productId;
     return o.productId === productId;
   });

   // Returns usernames associated with the ordered items matching the product
   const usernames = ordered.map(o => {
     return users.filter(u => u.userId === o.userId)[0].name;
   });

   // Finally returning the unique array of users removing the duplicated values
   const filtered = usernames.filter((u, i) => usernames.indexOf(u) === i);

   return filtered;
};


console.log(getUserNamesFromOrders("hexagon"));
```

You can also chain the process as following to make it short:

```
   const usernames = orders.filter(o => {
     const productId = products.filter(p => p.productName === productName)[0].productId;
     return o.productId === productId;
   }).map(o => {
     return users.filter(u => u.userId === o.userId)[0].name;
   });
```

But I've split the process for the explanation purpose as mentioned in the comment in the code.

Hope it helps!